# sql server update blocked by another transaction, concurrency in update

Tags: sql-server, locking

Two SP's are getting executed one after another and the second one is getting blocked by first one. They both are trying to update same table. Two SP's are as following

1. > CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP1]
   >   Begin
   >
   > SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SNAPSHOT;
   >   BEGIN TRANSACTION ImpSchd
   >
   > update Table t1 .......... ................................//updating
   >   a set of [n1,n2....n100] records
   >
   > COMMIT TRANSACTION ImpSchd
   >   SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL
   >   READ COMMITTED;
   >
   > END

2.

> CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP2]
>
> Begin
>
> update Table t1 .......... ................................//updating
>   a set of [n101,n102.....n200] records
>
> END

My question is when sp1 is running is snapshot level isolation why is it blocking sp2 (n both are updating different set of records)?

> If i run first sp for two different set of records simultaneously it
>   works perfectly.

How can I overcome this situation ?

If using the snapshot level isolation is to be set for each sp updating the same table then it would be a larger change.

if two sp has to update same records in a table, how should i handle that(both sp will update different columns)?

Answer (score 0):

Isolation levels only are for not blocking selects,so any DML wont be affected by Isolation levels.In this case update takes IX lock on table,page followed by taking xlock on row to update.Since you are updating in bulk ,table itself might have been locked due to lock escalation.Hope this helps

Comment: then when I run sp1 for two large set of records , how does that got sucessful without any blocking?

Comment: Can you clarify on two large set of records ,are they from different table

Comment: Updated answer as per comments

Comment: still it doesn't answer my problem(s)